# why is "hibernate.ejb.event.flush" required in spring persistence.xml

Tags: java, database, spring, persistence.xml

In my persistence.xml, I have

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.event.flush" value="xxx.persistence.hibernate.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener"/>
```

What is the role of that property in persistence.xml? What does it mean?

Thanks!